# Bubble sort sorts weirdly

Tags: java, algorithm

I just tried coding my first sorting algorithm aand it does weird things. I dont actually know, where this comes from but i think it has to do something with array length. because the first numbers always equal array length. Here i put the simple code i wrote in hopes, that somebody helps me debug it. Thank you very much in advance!!

```
public class BubbleSort {
    private static void sort(int[] pole) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pole.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < pole.length - i; j++) {
                if (pole[j-1] > pole[j]) {
                    int tm = pole[j-1];
                    pole[j-1] = j;
                    pole[j] = tm;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] pole = { 65, 210, 41, 23, 3, 2, 4, 78 }; 
        System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(pole));
        sort(pole);
        System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(pole));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `if` check. You're assigning the index of a value rather than the value itself - `pole[j-1] = j;`. So, you should correct it to:

```
...
if(pole[j-1] > pole[j]) {
    tm = pole[j-1];
    //assign the value here
    pole[j-1] = pole[j];
    pole[j] = tm;
}
...
```